# Mule Dataweave format :number

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I'm having an issue trying to parse a string to double this would be a sample code, it's returning an integer instead of type :double any ideas?

```
{
    "data": "22" as :number { format: "##.##" }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This, and only this, works for me;

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    data: "22" as :number as :string {format: ".00"} as :number
}
```

*format* only seems to add zeros when converting from a number to a string.
If "22" would have already been a number you wouldn't need the first :number conversion;

```
data: 22 as :string {format: ".00"} as :number
```

The latter number conversion makes it output as a float. Otherwise you would get a string, formatted according to the hosts locale.

And beware. When using`%output text/json` instead, the above code will in some cases produces *22.0* instead of *22.00*.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats more for formatting strings. Try this for decimal points:

```
{

    "data": "22" as :number {format: ".00"}

}
```

Comment: That works for all output types application/json etc. Just not application/java. Im guessing that what you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
%output application/json
%type currency = :string { format: "###,##0.00"} 
%function toLocalCurrency (currency) currency replace "." with "#" replace "," with "." replace "#" with ","
---
{
    usCurrencyWithOneDecimal: 900000.1 as :currency,
    brCurrency: toLocalCurrency(900000.1 as :currency),
    usCurrencyWithTwoDecimal: 900000.12 as :currency,
    usCurrencyWithThreeDecimal: 900000.124 as :currency,
    usCurrencyWithThreeDecimalRounding: 900000.125 as :currency,
    usCurrencyZero: 0 as :currency
}
```

The output is:

```
{
  "usCurrencyWithOneDecimal": "900,000.10",
  "brCurrency": "900.000,10",
  "usCurrencyWithTwoDecimal": "900,000.12",
  "usCurrencyWithThreeDecimal": "900,000.12",
  "usCurrencyWithThreeDecimalRounding": "900,000.12",
  "usCurrencyZero": "0.00"
}
```