# Mule dataweave: convert decimal to an integer

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to convert a decimal (78.22) to an integer (78) using Dataweave.

```
<root>
<MoneyAmountRequired>78.22</MoneyAmountRequired>
</root>
```

I try as below and it doesn't work if I add default 0

```
moneyAmountRequired: payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired as :number{format: "0"} default 0
```

Can some one please point out why it doesn't work when  default 0   is present.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use floor function of dataweave.

```
{
    root: {
        MoneyAmountRequired: floor payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :-

```
moneyAmountRequired: payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired as :string {format: "0"}as :number default 0
```

Here you need to convert it first in String `as :string` then in number `as :number`
This is the only way it seems to work !!
ref:- [Mule Dataweave format :number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281278/mule-dataweave-format-number)

Comment: The problem is having default 0. I want to have a default value if the value is not present but if I keep it, I can't convert decimal to integer. as :number {format: "0"} works perfectly fine without default 0

Answer (score 0):

Try myvalue: removeDecimal(28.23)

Comment: I get "There is no variable named 'removeDecimal' "

Comment: Can I know how you are doing it,because am getting it properly its a function call. can you post the dataweave script

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
moneyAmountRequired: payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired as :number {format: "##,##"} as :string {format: "##"} as :number
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
%dw 1.0
%output application/java

### %var regex = /(.\d+?)0+\b/

data replace regex with ""

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.

Answer (score 0):

```
((payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired as :string) splitBy '.')[0] as :number
```

If you prefer to use a function, then:

```
%function truncateDecimals(d) ((d as :string) splitBy '.')[0] as :number when d != null otherwise d
---
{value: truncateDecimals(payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired)}
```

Comment: There is a nice preview function that allows you to format your code correctly. Perhaps try it?

Answer (score 0):

After the number is formatted, it is indeed a string, but you are defaulting it to a number 0 instead of defaulting it to a string "0". But that would be enough if 'as :number' did not failed when the variable is null, which is in the first place the reason you need the default. Therefore, default it before converting it to a number as follows:

```
moneyAmountRequired: (payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired default "0") as :number{format: "0"}
```

Hope this will answer your question about the default 0 not working.

Answer (score -1):

Use this for

%dw 1.0

### %output application/json

{
    value : moneyAmountRequired: floor payload.root.MoneyAmountRequired as :number  default 0
}